# ipfs pubsub not working across two remote peers

Tags: publish-subscribe, ipfs

If I run this code on my pc, I see my message, but another person on a different pc running the same code doesn't see mine. Is this a NAT thing perhaps? Or am I using this wrong?

```
const Room = require("ipfs-pubsub-room");
const ipfs = require("ipfs");
ipfs.create({}).then(async (node) => {
  const room = new Room(node, "room-name");

  room.on("peer joined", (peer) => {
    console.log("Peer joined the room", peer);
  });

  room.on("peer left", (peer) => {
    console.log("Peer left...", peer);
  });

  // now started to listen to room
  room.on("subscribed", () => {
    console.log("Now connected!");
  });

  room.on("message", ({ from, data }) =>
    console.log(from, JSON.parse(data.toString()))
  );

  room.broadcast(JSON.stringify({ bla: "hello" }));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using this in Node.js or browser?

The problem should be that your peers are not connected between each other (or with a common set of peers running pubsub) to have the pubsub messages reliably forwarded. The first step for you to diagnose this is to use `node.swarm.peers()` and see if you have the other peer.

Considering your peer is not connected to the other person node, you need to manually connect it, or configure a discovery mechanism to help you (this is automatic discovery and connectivity is a known problem for the community and we will be working on improving this experience).
The simplest option is to use webrtc-star transport+discovery. You can see examples with it in [ipfs browser exchange files](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/blob/master/packages/ipfs-core/src/runtime/libp2p-browser.js#L21) and with [libp2p](https://github.com/libp2p/js-libp2p/tree/master/examples/libp2p-in-the-browser).

With this, you will likely see the other peers connected and then be able to exchange Pubsub messages. You can see more about the discovery mechanisms available in [Libp2p config.md](https://github.com/libp2p/js-libp2p/blob/master/doc/CONFIGURATION.md#peer-discovery) and [libp2p discovery examples](https://github.com/libp2p/js-libp2p/tree/master/examples/discovery-mechanisms).

Let me know if you could get your issue fixed

Comment: I will try it, thanks! This was on nodejs, but I'm curious - would your suggestions work the same if it were on browser? And same question about mobile networks?

Comment: Browser yes, but there are some pitfalls if you for example want a browser node to participate in the same pubsub topology as go nodes. This is because browser policies do not allow browser nodes to dial no wss+dns addresses and most of go nodes do not have wss+dns addresses in this moment. If it is a network of browser only it would work. Regarding mobile networks, I guess but it would be good to try it out.